# Creating muti user access login form

Tags: java, forms, swing, authentication, jframe

I have created a login form for a system which i have created. Currently i have only one user access login meaning only one login for the whole system. 
Here is what i want to do , i want to have multiple user logins such as for a doctor , nurse , admin . There should be restrictions as well, such as if the user is logged in as a doctor or nurse, the user can only view their details and where else if the user has logged in as admin , then the user can access any part in the system.

Here is what i have done so far:-

```
private void btnenterActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                         

    String password=new String (txtpassword.getPassword()); //method to get the password from password field
    String username=txtusername.getText();
    if(username.equals("admin") && password.equals("admin123"))
    {

        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Welcome to the System","WELCOME",JOptionPane.INFORMATION_MESSAGE);
    Main_menu enter=new Main_menu();

    enter.setVisible(true);
    close();
    }
    else
    {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame,"Wrong username/password","Invalid username or password",JOptionPane.ERROR_MESSAGE);
    }


}
```

I can use this same method to give different access logins but i cannot set an access level to an user, except by going to each and every form in the system and using "if" condition and restricting the user access level. 
But this isn't very effective enough for me, so is there any other method to do this in a simpler way ?

Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

I believe that normally you would create an authentication function, and then you would simply call that anywhere where the user needed to authenticate. Alternately, it's fairly common to group all of the restricted functions into a set of restricted pages, and call the authentication when the page is loaded, so that you don't have to verify it on each and every form.  One of the common methods is through cookies.  When the user logs in, you set a cookie for them.  The restricted pages call a check to make sure the user has that cookie, and if they don't, they get redirected to the login page.

I'm not a Java developer so I couldn't tell you what the code for that would be, but I believe that's the standard MO in PHP, and I do know many sites like to set cookies with Javascript (much to my dismay).

Comment: Well thx for the answer , but i am not sure about the cookie part because in java am not aware of such a method. 

Thanks anyways.

Comment: So it would appear that this is a local application?  I had assumed that this was a web app or at least had some server communication.  If this is a local application (and pardon me if this doesn't work in Java, but I would assume it would) you should be able to create a variable that holds an 'authenticatedLevel' variable, which could just be a number, and assign each user level a number.  Hard coded passwords like that are generally considered bad, better than that would be to store usernames and passwords in a file, possibly like Unix passwd files ( user:hashedPass )